# Is it possible to schedule trash cleaning?

Tags: trash, schedule

I was wondering if it is possible to do this, because I have to delete a lot of files during job day, and I prefer to do it on interface and no using *sudo rm*, so if it's possible... how?

For example, once a week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool for that: autotrash

```
pip3 install --user autotrash
```

(there is no apt install anymore) A cron job with

```
@daily ./home/rinzwind/.local/bin/autotrash -td 10
```

will once a day delete your trash. The `-d` deletes file older than 10 days. Adding `-t` will delete for all users. It has a couple of more features (like deleting based on entry and filesize, or on what is currently free in the trash).

There is also trash-cli

```
sudo apt install trash-cli
```

and

```
@daily /usr/bin/trash-empty
```

will delete trash once a day.

---

```
$ pip3 install --user autotrash
Collecting autotrash
  Downloading autotrash-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting arrow<0.18.0,>=0.17.0
  Downloading arrow-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 50 kB 2.2 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from arrow<0.18.0,>=0.17.0->autotrash) (2.8.1)
Installing collected packages: arrow, autotrash
  WARNING: The script autotrash is installed in '/home/rinzwind/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

and ...

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/.local/bin$ ./autotrash -td 10
rinzwind@discworld:~/.local/bin$
```

Comment: Can't find autotrash in Focal repositories. It used to be in backports, but not anymore.

Comment: added the pip3 install :)

Comment: excellent, thanks a lot!